# Unable to run flutter mobile application, DeviceStateChecker cancelled

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm unable to launch flutter mobile application in AVD. The project is setup in windows environment.

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi: Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
--------- beginning of main 08-12 15:27:58.372 I/DeviceStateChecker( 2351): >DeviceStateChecker cancelled Unhandled exception: Exit code
-1073740940 from: C:\Users\hc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:360:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:289:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:513:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:688:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:318:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:361:5) <asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39) <asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:389:23)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:449:26) <asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29) <asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:819:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:447:15) <asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:383:12) <asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:301:38) <asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)

Exited (255)
```